# How to arrange a list of numbers into column and row

Tags: python-3.x

I want to input 12 numbers and have it by column and rows but Im having a problem how to do that

```
lst = []
num = int(input("Enter 12 numbers:"))

for n in range(num):
    numbers = int(input(' '))
    lst.append(numbers)
```

I want the output to look ike this:
Thr numbers will only depend on the entered numbers

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 1 2 3

Comment: Can you add details as to what is the purpose of each of your `input` requests, and what is the expected format of the input? Also, how you determine how much numbers in each row?

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [] 
num = int(input("Enter 12 numbers:"))

while num > 0:
    lst.append(num % 10)
    num = int(num / 10)

lst.reverse()

for i in range(3):
    temp = ""
    for j in range(4):
        index = i * 3 + j
        temp += str(lst[index]) + " "
    print(temp)
```

Comment: That's result is what you want.

Comment: No. its up to you what 12 numbers you will input

Comment: You can change column instead of 4, row instead of 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a loop to print the list on the amount of rows you want. Say you want to print `lst` on `n` rows:

```
row_len = len(lst) // n
for i in range(0, len(lst), row_len):
    print(lst[i: i + row_len])
```